# update UUID column from a select in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a 2 tables let's say (**`Account`** and **`Customer`**) that uses UUID as the primary key without proper relationship, and I am trying to fix appropriately.

The `customer_id`(not the UUID (PK)) on `account` is the same thing as the `provider_customer_id` on `customer` table,

when I tried to update the `account` table by setting `customer_id` as the UUID of the `customer` table so as to reference the customer table from there with the script below

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE accounts
    MODIFY COLUMN customer_id BINARY(16) NOT NULL;
UPDATE accounts a
    INNER JOIN  customers c on a.customer_id = c.provider_customer_id
SET a.customer_id = (c.id)
WHERE c.provider_customer_id is not null ;

ALTER TABLE accounts
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ACCOUNTS_ON_CUSTOMER FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (id);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

mysql updated as expected, but the UUID is totally different from what was in the `customer` table this was what it was updated to

```
43313231-3443-4134-0000-000000000000
43313231-3634-3137-0000-000000000000
43313231-3436-4847-0000-000000000000
43313231-3443-4134-0000-000000000000
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Provide source data and desired final data state for it.

Comment: Do you have the same datatype on both tables?

Comment: Yes, they were not same datatype before, but I had to modify the destination column to  BINARY(16) which is the same datatype with the source column